# How to grab the order status of the last order in WooCommerce via a shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, orders

I'm trying to give our customers a better insight in their order status without going to their account. My plan is to print the info on the home page once someone has ordered.

[image: Sample of how I want it to look]

I'm struggling to get the order status to display elsewhere.

Here is the current code I've whipped up based on a code used to grab the product of the last order.

```php
function woostatus() {
    // Not available
    $na = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    
    // For logged in users only
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $na;

    // The current user ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get the WC_Customer instance Object for the current user
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

    // Get the last WC_Order Object instance from current customer
    $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();
    
    // When empty
    if ( empty ( $last_order ) ) return $na;
     
     // Get order date
    $order_items = $last_order->get_status();
    
    // Latest WC_Order_Item_Product Object instance
    $last_item = end( $order_items );

    // Pass product ID to products shortcode
    return $order_items;
}  
// Register shortcode 
add_shortcode( 'display_woostatus', 'woostatus' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$order_items = $last_order->get_status()` will return a string and is therefore not an array. So using `end( $order_items )` is a superfluous step.

Use instead:

```php
function woostatus() {
    // Not available
    $na = __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' );
    
    // For logged in users only
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return $na;

    // The current user ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Get the WC_Customer instance Object for the current user
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );

    // Get the last WC_Order Object instance from current customer
    $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();
    
    // When empty
    if ( empty ( $last_order ) ) return $na;
    
    // Get order status
    $order_status = $last_order->get_status();
    
    // Return
    return $order_status;
} 
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode( 'display_woostatus', 'woostatus' );
```

---

SHORTCODE USAGE

In an existing page:

```
[display_woostatus]
```

Or in PHP:

```
echo do_shortcode('[display_woostatus]');
```